# Resize System.Array using Array.Resize

Tags: arrays, vb.net, resize, system.array

Hello there StackOverflowers.

I was wondering if it's possible to resize a System.Array using the shared method Array.Resize.

I can't seem to get it to work; it only works if I, for instance, write: 
`Array.Resize(DirectCast(Array, Byte()), Size)`

But I cannot rely on DirectCasts, as the program will not know what types the arrays are.

Thank you.

Comment: Instead of using System.Array, could you use a generic method with generic type parameter T and the array passed as T() - then your DiectCast would work (casting to T()).

Comment: That sounds interesting, but the thing is that I am working with jagged arrays; thus I don't know whether it will be T()()() or T().